# Java - Binary decryption

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, character-encoding, binary

beginner here! I was just wondering if anyone could help? I am currently writing a Encryption/Decryption programme in Java and need to reverse binary which is inputted. I have managed to do encrypt it into binary, however, I am struggling to now decrypt it (e.g - The word HELLO has been encrypted , but I now need to create a function so that it can read the binary and change it back to the text.)

Any help would be appreciated! This is the code I used for my original binary cipher in the encryption part.

```
String temp="";
    for(int i=0;i<message.length();i++)
    {
        temp=Integer.toBinaryString(message.charAt(i));
        for(int j=temp.length();j<8;j++)
        {
            temp="0"+temp;
        }
        encryptText+=temp+" ";
    }
```

I have tried various different measures but being as I have just started out a little guidance would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: There is no encryption here. Just conversion to zoned binary.

Comment: You are encoding the number, not encrypting.

Comment: I think you  are trying to convert to binary, not to a binary string. For that you convert to a byte array using `String#getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII): byte[]`. If you are trying to implement ROT13 then you are trying to convert each character to an index, perform the encryption and then turn the new index back into a character.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get a fixed-length Binary String, try this:

```
private static String toBinaryString(final int  value) {

    final String binaryString  = Integer.toBinaryString(value);

    final char[]          lead = new char[Integer.SIZE - binaryString.length()]; 
    Arrays.fill          (lead, '0');
    return String.valueOf(lead).concat(binaryString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there would be no space between every group of 8 bits 0/1:

```
for (int i = 0; i + 7 < message.length(); i += 8) {
    String temp = message.substring(i, i + 8);
    int c = Integer.parseInt(temp, 2); // Base 2, binary
    decryptText += (char)c;
}
```

Space separated:

```
for (String temp : message.split(" ")) {
    if (!temp.isEmpty()) {
        int c = Integer.parseInt(temp, 2); // Base 2, binary
        decryptText += (char)c;
    }
}
```